# Datatables Search/Filter using RegEx Issues

Tags: jquery, regex, datatables

I'm trying to use Datatables filter function to do something simple (I thought). Based on the selected radio button, I want to exclude or include rows that have no value (i.e., are empty) for a specific column. Like so:

```
$("#full_table").DataTable({
initComplete: function() {
            var table = $('#full_table').DataTable();
            $('input[type=radio][name=exclude]').change(function() {
        if (this.value == 'incblanks') {
            table
                    .columns(0)
                    .search( '' ) 
                    .draw();
        }
        else if (this.value == 'removeblanks') {
           table
                    .columns(0)
                    .search( '^(?!\s*$).+', true, false ) //THIS ISN'T WORKING
                    .draw();
        }
    });
        }
    });
```

I noted which part isn't working above. Basically, if you select Yes...then all rows are included using `.search( '' )`, then, if you want to exclude the rows that have a blank for column(0), then I was trying to do a regex for any non-blank character `.search( '^(?!\s*$).+', true, false )`, but this isn't working. I get no data back in the table, but no errors.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that your `code` *does* actually work, [check out the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9kr68o5L/). (I used both blank and "only spaces" values to represent empty cells and they are successfully filtered out)

Possibly you are using an older version of Datatables?  Empty cells seem to have [illuminated some bugs](https://www.google.com/search?q=datatables%20search%20for%20empty%20cells) in older versions. Have you upgraded to the newest?

Comment: I'm using the most up to date version served from datatables' CDN, so that isn't the issue. Thanks for doing the fiddle. Shows I'm not entirely crazy.

Comment: I'm also using server side processing and I feel like I've read something about this being an issue with regex search. Any thoughts?

Comment: no, but I would think you're probably on the right track, since we know the code from a client-side perspective is fine...

Comment: That's definitely the issue. I did a test switching back to client-side instead of server side and the regex works. Now...how to fix it.

Comment: I believe i read that regex search doesn't work with server-side processing, unfortunately...but good luck!